# JQUERY get values from multiple selects on page with multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page that has several forms created using a while loop and each form has four selects.  I am trying to work out how I can check each of the selects belonging to the current form (the one containing the button clicked) to confirm if any been selected.  All of the forms are wrapped in a single div called `#audit_content`.

The intention is to check that if the variable `grade` isn't a certain value then the script checks if any of the selects have been selected.

(The value `$i` is created during the while loop, used to uniquely identify each form)

the html

```
    <form id="audit_form<? echo $i; ?>">
      <select name="grade" class="grade<? echo $i; ?>">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
      <select>    
      <select name="patient" class="reason_select">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="exposure" class="reason_select">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="equipment" class="reason_select">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="positioning" class="reason_select">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    <input type="button" name="audit_submit" class="audit_submit audit_submit_btn ie7_submit" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" class="form_id" value="<? echo $i; ?>" >
 </form>
```

The JQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#audit_content').on("click", ".audit_submit", function(){
      var form_id = $(this).prev('.form_id').val();
      var grade = $('.grade'+form_id).val();
             if(grade != 1){
      $('select.reason_select').each(function(){
          alert($(this).text())
             }
        });
</script>
```

The script as it is displays the values of every select with the class `reason_select` on the page which I realise is because I haven't told it to check a specific form, thats the bit I'm stuck at.

Comment: $('.grade'+form_id) - I can't see the target of this selector in the HTML.

Comment: Don't show your PHP, show your HTML.

Comment: I only showed the php so you would kow where the value $i came into it

Comment: The JavaScript throws a SyntaxError: Unexpected token: }

Comment: the javascript works fine on my system, perhaps you tried before I'd finsihed adding the extra stuff

Comment: There should be no `$i` in the HTML/JavaScript (unless you have a specific *JavaScript* variable by that name); JavaScript runs on the client, *after* the [tag:php]'s finished its work.

Comment: No, it's not valid JavaScript. For example, you have four `{`'s, but only two `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button shown is outside the form, not inside as mentioned.

To isolate any repeating type widget look for the parent of that widget, then search only within it:
Moving the button inside the form would make it very easy by doing:

```
$('#audit_content').on("click", ".audit_submit", function () {
    var form=$(this).closest('form')
    var selects=form.find('select');
// do somthing with selects

})
```

Comment: hi, the button is within the form, the button was added after I'd posted the question because someone else want to see the code for the button

Comment: regardless...where the button is isn't critical....the main concept is to isolate the parent of the module and search within. This is a common pattern when working with any repeating type widgets in a page be they forms, rows, custom modules or whatever

Comment: thanks, but how would I check if any of the selects have a value?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the script to

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#audit_content').on("click", ".audit_submit", function () {
          var form = $(this).prev('form');
          var grade = $('select[name="grade"]', form).val();
          if (grade != '1') {
              $('select.reason_select', form ).each(function () {
                  alert($(this).text());
              });
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

---

In the script you have posted there are several missing `)` and `}` so it should create syntax errors..

You mention

> *current form (the one containing the button clicked)*

but your button is not contained in the form, that is why i changed the code to `form = $(this).prev('form')`

Comment: the button is within the form, I was asked to add the code for the button after I'd posted and forgot to put it within the form tag